# Bitmap bytes exceeded?

Tags: android, bitmap, logcat, live-wallpaper

When I run my live-wallpaper the first time everything works fine. But after that the live-wallpaper preview will say "Unfortunately... has stopped. But then it will work again after a couple of seconds. I noticed that right when when it gives me that error screen this appears in my logcat:

```
Process: live.wallpaper.dav3.spacelivewallpaper, PID: 2748
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 16777228 byte allocation with 3319256 free bytes and 3MB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:726)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:547)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:575)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:605)
            at com.dav3.java.Background.<init>(Background.java:66)
            at com.dav3.java.MainService$WallpaperEngine.onCreate(MainService.java:47)
            at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$Engine.attach(WallpaperService.java:895)
            at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$IWallpaperEngineWrapper.executeMessage(WallpaperService.java:1166)
            at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:37)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

It is telling me (I think) that I have exceeded the bite limit for my bitmaps. Can anyone tell me of a way to fix this, are my bitmap files to big? Again the wallpaper works fine but it always has that crashing text before and after I set it, so it can get very annoying, but then a few seconds later it will start working. I will be grateful for any help, thank you! =)

Comment: it may be due to size of bitmaps. You can also use large heap by allocating in manifest file. largeheap="yes"

Comment: Show the code where you create/initialize your Bitmaps, there are ways to make them smaller.